# getting solution to an equation as a variable with subscripts

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

in `Mathematica` for some function `f[x]` I want to `Solve[f[x] == a, x]` and record the solution as `Subscript[x, 1, a], Subscript[x, 2, a]`, and so on.

what is the neatest way to do this if

1. I know how many solutions exists
2. I do not know how many solutions exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way which should work for both cases is to do something like

```
MapIndexed[(Subscript[x, #2[[1]], a] = x /. #1) &,  Solve[f[x] == a, x]]
```

Comment: In the case one would like to replace the value `a` in the subscript with an actual value for `a` (which, I think, is quite conceivable) one has to replace the first `a` by `a_`